# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException : I/O Error on POST Request

Tags: java, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

While trying to execute a REST call using restTemplate.postForEntity of spring framework i am getting the  below error from weblogic

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException : I/O Error on POST Request
.
.
Caused By : Java.io.IOException : An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Same REST Call is working from normal java main method.Method call from Java Main Method was also giving the same exception but its able to connect to the https url after adding the below two lines

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","pass");
```

If adding the above lines resolved the issue in normal java project, what is the difference with weblogic?

How do i debug the certificate issue when code is deployed in weblogic server?